# Getting View of One to Many where Column Names are repeated with Indexed field

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate, materialized-view

I have 4 tables joined with an inner join.
2 of these joined tables are 1 to Many relationships. Consider the following example return where t1 is table 1, t2 is table 2 and so forth. table 1 has a 1 to many relationship with table 2 and like wise with table3.

I would like to get a result set back like

```
t1.Column1,  `t2.ItemDescItemOrdinalColumn1,t2.ItemDescItemOrdinalColumn2,
t3.ItemDescItemOrdinalColumn1, t3.ItemDescItemOrdinalColumn2
```

`

Where ItemDesc can be a literal, ItemOrdinal is an index number that is stored in the table for the group.

```
T1, Id, Description;
T2, Id, T1.Id, ItemOrdinal, ItemDesc, other columns;
T3, Id, T1.Id, ItemOrdinal, ItemDesc, other columns;
```

I am trying to model after an XML file to import it into a database and also model that in a view.

```
<Inventory>
<Site>

<Item1Amt>37.00</Item1Amt>
<Item1Desc>Molded Plastic Handle</Item1Desc>
<Item1Qty>2.0</Item1Qty>

<Item2Amt>34.00</Item2Amt>
<Item2Desc>Chrome plated Knob</Item2Desc>
<Item2Qty>8.0</Item2Qty>

</site>
</Inventory>
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99496f/1) :

Expected output :
Columns Named
[t1.Description] , Item[ItemOrdinal]ColumnNameQTY,Item[ItemOrdinal]ColumnNameAMT

I hope by adding the xml I am trying to import and the sql fiddle table will help me. Maybe I am wrong in my attempt or design - but I am trying to flatten out the result set in a view.

EDIT:
Added the Columns in DbFiddle to look more like the xml I have. To make it more readable I am showing Item1Amt,Item1Desc,Item1Qty; . but this row would repeat to Item 6 - I am doing a view here because an older system will need to look at the data. And that is how the older db system was designed.

```
Tbl_1.Description, Item1Amt,   Item1Desc    , Item1Qty, 
           M_5888,   3.0   , M Number 5888_1,       12,
```

For better readability this is a Continuation of Row Result :

```
Item2Amt,  Item2Desc     , Item2Qty, 
    51.0, M Number 5888_2,      5
```

[DbFiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=142e8813e949161eb66209b9a7155045)

Comment: Create a fiddle with tables structures and a couple of records, and show desired result for this data.

Comment: @Akina I will try to get that tonight.

Comment: @Akina ok I added a fiddle and also more explanation of what I am trying to do and the xml I am trying to translate.

Comment: Well. Now please *show desired result for **this** data*. PS. I have recreated the fiddle [there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0479c1e34042d6c2d999caa5b0477863) - sqlfiddle.com is not stable and fails for me too often...

Comment: @Akina sorry my description was not clear so I have added the required columns in the dbfiddle and also provided the abbreviated row result - I split the row result so that it is more readable but it is one record of multiples. I am thinking the original table was originally built with pivot tables from excel.

Comment: *so I have added the required columns in the dbfiddle and also provided the abbreviated row result* And where is the link?

Comment: @Akina at the very bottom of the post above. sorry thought the original link was perm.

Comment: @Akina the more I look at the problem - I see there is a command called Pivot maybe this is what I need to use in order to create the view to flatten out the row results.